# TFS/VSTS, refer to a variable in a variable

Tags: variables, tfs, build, release

I wonder if its possible to refer to a variable in another variable using variables in VSTS and/or TFS.

For instance lets assume we have the following variables:

- var1:http://environment1.somedomain.local/api/endpoint/1
- var2:http://environment1.somedomain.local/api/endpoint/2
- var3:http://environment1.somedomain.local/api/endpoint/3

what I would like to achive is something like:

- varDomain:environment1.somedomain.local
- var1:http://$(varDomain)/api/endpoint/1
- var2:http://$(varDomain)/api/endpoint/2
- var3:http://$(varDomain)/api/endpoint/3

and the be able to use var1,var2 and var3 later on in my build be able to use these as tokens for my web.conifg "transform".. and/or use them in the tasks for my build and/or release.

Anyone aware if its possible to combine variables in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The examples you provided work perfectly. So the answer to your question is, "yes".